# SLURM: print out name of several nodes in one job

Tags: bash, slurm

I would like to submit one job to two nodes and print a hello from each node processing my job, e.g.

> Hello World from node_21
>
> Hello World from node_44

my .cpp is

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::cout << "Hello World from " << argv[1] << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

and my bash is

```
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH --nodes  2            
#SBATCH --ntasks 2            
#SBATCH --time=0:01:00        
#SBATCH --job-name="hostname" 
#SBATCH --output=helloworld.out
#SBATCH --error=helloworld.er

module load gcc
srun ./helloworld $%N
```

as I searched through https://slurm.schedmd.com/sbatch.html#lbAH to find out, how to get the hostname.

Unfortunately my output is:

> Hello World from %N
>
> Hello World from %N

Comment: "filename patterns" are understood only by a few directives/options of `srun`; never as argument of an external command. You can use `srun ./helloworld "$(hostname)"` instead

Comment: This results in 
Hello World from node_21
Hello World from node_21

Comment: My bad; only the command executed through `srun` will be executed on all the nodes. As you're using C++, you can just call `gethostname` in the code.

Comment: Or wrap the command in an other shell: `srun sh -c './helloworld "$(hostname)"'`

Comment: god bless you. I was going insane :)